# Unable to fetch values from dynamially generated multi-select boxes in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multiple-select, dynamic-values

I have a simple form which contains a multi-select box which is dynamically generated on a button click.

A demo of the form is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/fg10v39n/).

As it is a multiple select box, the user will be able to select any number of values from the select box & it should be saved into the database. So, I declared the select box as an array..like this.

```
  <select name="select2[]" size="3" multiple="multiple">
         <option value="11">eleven</option>
        <option value="12">twelve</option>
        <option value="13">thirette</option>
        <option value="14">fourteen</option>
        <option value="15">fifteen</option>
        <option value="16">sixteen</option>
        <option value="17">seventeen</option>
        <option value="18">eighteen</option>
        <option value="19">nineteen</option>
        <option value="20">twenty</option>     
  </select>
```

But as I told earlier the multiple select box will be generated multiple times as per user's choice, all the datas that are entered should be saved. So I change the name of the selectbox using jquery.

The name of the select boxes will be like select2[]1, select2[]2, select2[]3 and so on (which is invalid; not an array) but it should be like select21[], select22[], select23[] and so on which is a valid way of declaring an array.
I am not able to fetch the array in server side using PHP as follows

```
if  ($total_count>0)
        {  //echo $total_count;
            for($i=0;$i<=$total_count;$i++)
            {
                // generated as select2[]1,select2[]2,select2[]3 ,... which is not valid.
                // thus invalid argument to foreach
                if($this->input->post('select2[]'.$i)){
                $data2=array(
                'field1' =>$this->input->post('select2[]'.$i)
                );      
            $this->db->insert('table1',$data2);

            }
         }
```

Is there any workaround for this heck?

Comment: Put the name as select[1][] , select[2][] and so on

Comment: It's dynamically generated. Read the question carefully. @Lalit Sharma

Comment: Well then generate it that way dynamically …

Comment: I know its generating dynamically you need to add one counter variable to achieve above given file name pattern that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are naming your select boxes as `name="select2[]1"` instead it should be like `name="select21[]" , name="select22[]"`. This will become an array and can be accessed via `php` file as 
`$_POST['select21']`.

The naming is being done in your javascript like this

```
`$(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + i);`
```

i suggest changing it to

```
$(this).attr("name",i+$(this).attr("name"));
```

---

A more simpler example would be like

```
<script>
var elem,i=0;
            $("#add_company").click(function () {
                elem = '<select name="select'+i+'[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">' +
                    '<option value="11">eleven</option>' +
                    '<option value="12">twelve</option>' +
                    '<option value="13">thirette</option>' +
                    '<option value="14">fourteen</option>' +
                    '<option value="15">fifteen</option>' +
                    '<option value="16">sixteen</option>' +
                    '<option value="17">seventeen</option>' +
                    '<option value="18">eighteen</option>' +
                    '<option value="19">nineteen</option>' +
                    '<option value="20">twenty</option>' +
                    '</select>';
                $("#frmHolder").append(elem);
                i++;
            });
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form2" action="get_test.php" method="post">
    <div id="frmHolder"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit the Form" />
</form>
```

and in `get_test.php` just dump the `$_POST` and see the output.

eg.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
    var_dump($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the main issue is in your form use POST method in your form . You are using GET method in form while fetching the values with post method

```
<form id="form1" name="form2" action="" method="post">
<div id="add_company_div" class="addcomp" style='display: none;'>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 own_pad">
  <select name="select2[]" size="3" multiple="multiple">
         <option value="11">eleven</option>
        <option value="12">twelve</option>
        <option value="13">thirette</option>
        <option value="14">fourteen</option>
        <option value="15">fifteen</option>
        <option value="16">sixteen</option>
        <option value="17">seventeen</option>
        <option value="18">eighteen</option>
        <option value="19">nineteen</option>
        <option value="20">twenty</option>     
  </select>
  </div>

  <div id="hide_company" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 own_pad minus">
    Click this DIV to Close
  </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="start_count_value"  name="start_count_value" value="" />   
<input type="hidden" name="class_count" class="class_count" value="" />
<div class="box-footer clearfix no-border no_pad comp-foot">
  <div id="add_company" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left">Generate Multiple Select Boxes</div>
</div>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="submit" value="Submit the Form" />
</form>
```

try to use this php code

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $select=$_POST['select2'];
    foreach($select as $key=>$selects)
    {
        echo $selects; // will echo 11 12..................20

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if  ($total_count>0)
        {  //echo $total_count;
            for($i=0;$i<=$total_count;$i++)
            {
                // generated as select2[]1,select2[]2,select2[]3 ,... which is not valid.

   // thus invalid argument to foreach
            if(isset($_POST['select2'][$i])){
            $data2=array(
            'field1' =>$_POST['select2'][$i]
            );      
        $this->db->insert('table1',$data2);

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try your same code but just like this:

```
if($this->input->post('select2'. $i .'[]')){
$data2=array(
 'field1' =>$this->input->post('select2'. $i .'[]')
);
```